# cython use class wrapper pointer

Tags: python, c++, pointers, cython

I'm new to cython and maybe i'm missing some base info, so be patient. What i want to do is create a c++ object in python, modify it and return the object's pointer to a c++ function. Basically i have:

```
// headers.h

class A {
    A();
    void modifyA()
}

class B {
    B();
    void useA(A *a);
}
```

```
# headers.pxd

cdef extern from "headers.h":
    cdef cppclass A:
        void modifyA()

    cdef cppclass B:
        void useA(A *a)
```

```
# PyA.pyx

cdef class PyA:
    cdef A *pa

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.pa = new A()

    def modifyA(self):
        self.pa.modifyA()
```

Now, as far as i understand, when i instantiate PyA from python code, an A object is created in c++ and a pointer is stored inside the new PyA object. What i want to do is use that pointer like:

```
# PyB.pyx

cdef class PyB:
    cdef B *b

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.b = new B()

    def useA(self, pyA: PyA):
        self.b.useA(pyA.pa)
```

but it gives me "Cannot convert Python object to 'A *'" and i can't understand why... Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: I've downvoted because you've edited your example code significantly. It's frustrating for answerers to try to keep up with constantly changing questions. And of course there's no guarantee that you won't change it again if someone answers your question as it is now

Comment: Can you please revert to the original question? Just add the extra information in an __edit__ section. I already detected the issue in your code and I'm willing to help, but I expect the question to be useful for other people searching the same problem. The idea of StackOverflow is not only to answer individual questions, but mostly to build collective knowledge.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, i thought that was the best way to correct my question. I'll leave it without the imports since that seems to be irrelevant after ibarrond's answer. Let me know if i can improve readability or something else.

Comment: Now, the new error you were having came again from the same issue described in the answer. Make sure you define any cdef or cpdef function you want to share across `pyx` files in a corresponding `.pxd` header, and then import it with `cimport`.

Comment: Hi ibarrond, thank you for your help. It took me a while to understand that even python-like objects can have headers, so initially i wrongly interpreted your answer, but everything is working fine now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Cannot convert Python object to 'Something'" error in Cython generally means Cython is not detecting the type of an object/property, and thus believes it will be a Python object, only available at runtime.

That being said, you have to make sure Cython understands the type. In your particular case, you can choose between:

- Having a single `.pyx` (merging both `.pyx` files), for cython to be able to directly determine that `pyA.pa` is of type `A*`.
- Declaring a "cython header file" or `.pxd` file, which will work much like a `.h` file in C++ by declaring types of objects, functions and classes.

The second case would look like this:

```
# PyA.pxd
cdef class PyA:
    cdef A *pa
```

```
# PyB.pyx
from PyA cimport PyA    # import the PyA class from PyA.pxd definition
cdef class PyB:
# [...]
```

Comment: This is the right answer. It's important that you `cimport PyA` rather than `import` it